# Saving a 2D array on a ParseObject

Tags: java, arrays, parse-platform

I'm trying to save a 2D int array, int[][], to a ParseObject called group:

```
        ParseObject newGroup = new ParseObject("Group");
        newGroup.put("group_name",grpName);
        int[][] grpTable = new int[grpSize][grpSize];
        initializeTable(grpTable,grpSize);
        newGroup.put("group_table",grpTable);
```

on this last line the app crashes, throwing:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid type for value: class [[I

Is it impossible to save a 2D array in parse? Can you offer an alternative?

I know for a regular array I can just use add function, but it won't work here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it is possible.

I believe the easiest way would be to store the data in a single dimension array, and keep a counter of where each row would end.

This is because 2D arrays basically ARE 1D arrays, that are just presented differently.

E.g:

```
[1,2,3
 4,5,6
 7,8,9];
```

Could be represented as

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
```

and as long as you know that each row only has 3 elements, it is trivial to convert it back to your 2D array.

Here is how your above code would look, obviously I would need to see the initializeTable method to be able to fix it completely.

```
ParseObject newGroup = new ParseObject("Group");
newGroup.put("group_name", grpName);

// Make the array grpSize*grpSize to handle rows/cols
// I.e if you normally had a 3x3 2d Array, this one would just be
// 9x1 instead.
int[] grpTable = new int[grpSize*grpSize];

// *Change initializeTable() to us a 1d array*.
initializeTable(grpTable, grpSize);
newGroup.put("group_table", grpTable);
```

Comment: It *is* possible more directly than you suggest.  Parse supports JSONObject and JSONArray as attribute types.  To the extent a java object is translatable to these (and certainly nested arrays of ints is), it can be saved and retrieved from a parse.com (see https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#objects-data-types).

Comment: Moreover, 2D arrays are not merely 1D arrays represented differently.  2D arrays also convey dimensionality.  In other words, serializing a 4x4 into a 16x1 discards the information that there were originally 4 rows and 4 columns.  How would one know not to subsequently interpret a 16x1 as a 2x8?

Comment: Your first point is true, and would be a more optimal solution. For the second part, we agree. You lose information convertin a 4x4 into a 16x1, which is why I suggested keeping track of the row position in the element.

Comment: I found a solution: I created a class containing a 2D int array.

@ParseClassName("Group") public class DebtTable extends ParseObject

and i now store an instant of that class instead of an actual 2D array. Thank you anyway!